# Installing Kaldi on MacOS Catalina -- error with zlib

Tags: zlib, macos-catalina, kaldi

I am trying to work with the [DiscVoice](https://github.com/jcvasquezc/DisVoice) Library which requires the Kaldi Library. In order to install Kaldi, I needed to run `extras/check_dependencies.sh` to check the dependencies of the program, and I am currently getting:

```
extras/check_dependencies.sh: zlib is not installed.
extras/check_dependencies.sh: The following prerequisites are missing; install them first:
   zlib1g-dev
```

I have been trying to install the zlib library, and have been unsuccessful. I have tried `brew install zlib`, which runs successfully but when I run the `extras/check_dependencies.sh` the output is not changed to reflect that.

I am working on macOS Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

zlib is already there in macOS. You don't need to install it.

You might want to examine `extras/check_dependencies.sh` to see *how* it is looking for zlib. macOS does not store its headers files or library files in the usual locations.

Comment: regarding to MKL - checking the latest mkl system requirements (https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-intel-mkl-2020-system-requirements.html), you could see MKL supports this os and therefore could be install on your system.

Comment: This is what the `check_dependencies.sh` file contains: 

```# Cannot check this without a compiler.
if have "$CXX" && ! echo "#include <zlib.h>" | $CXX -E - >&/dev/null; then
  echo "$0: zlib is not installed."
  add_packages zlib-devel zlib1g-dev
fi```

Where is zlib located on mac, and how could I change its location to work with Kaldi?

Answer (score 0):

Okay.. Assuming you actually need to install `kaldi`, and not just running the script to check its deps, i can surely say that you should try OPTION[2] from `INSTALL` manual in the root kaldi repo.

It says to use `cmake` installation, by instruction placed in `kaldi/cmake/`.

For macOS Catalina you have to do three steps to build and install kaldi. These steps, as said in `kaldi/cmake/INSTALL`:

1. `mkdir -p build && cd build`
2. `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../dist ..`  — after two last dots you can place cmake configuring flags, but let's assume you don't need them, so, just use the command exactly as it placed there. **last two dots are important part of the command, don't miss them.**
3. `cmake --build . --target install -- -j8`  — `8` is amount of CPU-cores of your computer, so you can choose less, in my case it was 4.

Second step will give you some warnings and missing repos. You can ignore them if at the end you see three lines of this kind:

```
...
-- Configuring done (1.8s)
-- Generating done (6.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/<user>/kaldi/build
```

(full path of course can be different on your machine)

And after that you can run third command from the list. It should build everything.

P.S. I tried different ways to install, none of them worked. But this one at least finished the installation.

P.S.S. before building and installing kaldi I made `brew install openblas`, but i can't say if it is necessary step, because instead of OpenBLAS kaldi should work with framework `Accelerate`, which is preinstalled with Catalina (actually i don't know for sure, but i did not installed it exclusively).

P.S.S.S. on Catalina 10.15.7 installed without errors by Cmake, step by step as instructed in `kaldi/cmake/INSTALL` file. No oneMKL used (there is no free distributable version of it for macOS now, even if you can find support for it in the list of OSes on official site, as @Gennady.F said in comments; [see this respond from moderator of Intel forum, 2022](https://community.intel.com/t5/oneAPI-Registration-Download/Where-can-I-find-older-versions-such-2021-x-of-oneMKL-or-oneAPI/m-p/1417725)).